# Prevent new line with TypeWriter effect in React

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors

```
<h3 >I'm
    <Typewriter className="inline"        
           
           options={{             
            
           strings:["Developer", "Designer", "Content Creater"],
           autoStart:true,
           delay:75,
           loop:true
           }}
           
           />     
           
 </h3>
```

How to prevent new line with TypeWriter effect in React?
The TypeWriter effect seems to insert a new line when I implement it, but I would really prefer it to read out on the same line. Please see
I want "I m Developer" in one line but its showing in different line Please help
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJDKI.png)
I want it in one line no new line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the "I'm" in the typewriter effect:

```
<Typewriter
  onInit={(typewriter) => {
    const words = ["Developer", "Designer", "Content Creater"];
    typewriter.typeString("I'm ");
    
      for (let index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
        typewriter.typeString(words[index]).pauseFor(500).deleteChars(words[index].length);
      }
     typewriter.start();
  }}
/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mq4rt7xj/